# Translation manager

Tags: translation-manager

[image]I want to know the flow for translating any content for the following:
Global Content -- Lets say I have to translate it to German and French and have two content publications (Content German and Content French) How will the translation happens for a global content to French and German, will the component  be localised in Content German and Content French publications? And if localised then next time when the change happens in Global Content how will the new changes flow to Content German and Content French because my component is already localised at these publications.

This ppt slide I have taken from the Translation deck provided by Tridion for Translation

Answer (score 2):

When you configure the Tridion Translation Manager, you set up a source publication, and one or more target publications. The source publication contains components in the language you want to translate from (global content), the source publications contain the components in the languages you translate to (in your case, one publication for german, and one publication for french).

When you create a new component in your global content publication, you can choose to send it for translation. Here, you can define to which language(s) you wish to translate it to.

Then, there is a whole workflow of translating, reviewing, etc, which happens outside of the Tridion CMS, and finally, the translated content is sent back to tridion, where it is localized in the target publications.

When you edit a global component that is already translated before, you can re-send it for translation, and the localized target component will then be overwritten.

So, it is advised not to edit a translated component manually, as your manual changes will be overwritten.

Comment: does GlobalLink GUI works the same way?

Comment: do we need to write the workflows or there are workflows provided by Translation.com

Comment: Hi Harald, there is one more question: If I want to change a local content which needs to flow to 2 multilingual country then I need to trigger translation again. Does it mean that we have two TMS layer in our blue printing?

Comment: I don't know about GlobalLink GUI.
Regarding the workflows, the translation manager connects to some other sdl software used by translators. Normally, the company providing the translation services set up these workflows for you (that all depends what contract you have with them).

I am not sure what you mean with your question about two TMS layers. Could you clarify this please ?

Comment: plz see the image I have attached with my question. I have highlighted 2 layers with red color. By two layers of Translation I meant to say we are doing translations at 2 levels.

Comment: The reason there are two layers in the image is that the last language (Belgium French) is not "translated" from the same source as the others - it is translated from French. So there is one layer with English to German/French/Dutch and one layer with French to Belgium French. If all your target languages are translated from the same source you do not need two layers.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but i believe in that case, you could add a second translation configuration, where you use the french publication as source, and the french/belgium as target. You should also check this with the company setting up the translation system, as they will have to set this up as well.